# Basic javascript function issue concatenate

Tags: javascript

I am learning JS , and i am trying to do this :

> define a function named eat that takes an argument named   food that is expected to be a string.
>
> Inside the function return the food argument like this:
>
> ```
>  return food + ' tasted really good.';
> ```
>
> Inside of the parentheses of console.log(), call the eat() function
>   with   the string bananas as the argument.

Here is my code :

```
function eat(food) {
  return food + 'tasted really good.';
}
console.log(eat('bannanas'));
```

Thing is that i get 'bannanas' to concatenate with other text *(**bannanastasted** really good.)*, 
can someone tell me where I am making a mistake . Thank you. :)

Comment: When you ask a question, please tell us: 1. What happened 2. What should have happened 3. What you want to happen 4. (optional) Your opinion on why is happened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a `space`

```
function eat(food) {
  return food + ' tasted really good.';
}
console.log(eat('bannanas'));
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!  I really didn't knew that space is required.